# Flutter -> Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
          products = responseJson;
          itemCounts = products.length;
          var result= 0;

          for (var item in products) {
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
               result = int.parse(item["total_amount"])* int.parse(item["product_price"]);
              print(result);
            }
          }

        });
      }
    }
```

I'm developing a mobil application in flutter. I have a math problem in the for. The data comes from API. and I need to multiply in the code below.

```
for (var item in products) {
   for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
       result = int.parse(item["total_amount"])* int.parse(item["product_price"]);
           print(result);
   }
}
```

I take a mistake. that mistake here.

```
E/flutter ( 9301): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item["total_amount"]` & `item["product_price"]` are likely already of type `int`. `int.parse` only takes a `String` as a parameter so you're getting an error that say int is not a subtype of String.

Remove both instances of `int.parse` to fix this error.

```dart
for (var item in products) {
   for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
       result = item["total_amount"] * item["product_price"];
           print(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: I try what you say. It gives this error this time.

E/flutter (10304): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'other'

Comment: @FesaTR Likely only one of them is an int and the other is a String. Print them both and find which one still needs to be parsed. A debugger would tell you as well.

Comment: I solved this problem. I changed that in database. It was varchar. I had int. İt had been solved thanks